# How can I open an .mp4 video through quicktime player?

Tags: python, video

```
import time
class Video(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QuickTimePlayer.exe"

    def play(self):
        from os import startfile
        startfile(self.path)

class Movie_MP4(Video):
    type = "MP4"

movie = Movie_MP4(r"C:\Users\A\1.mp4")
movie.play()
```

I am able to play windows media player file using this code if I change "C:/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QuickTimePlayer.exe" to path.

How can I get quicktime to play my video?

Comment: Startfile should take the mp4 input as its argument as opposed to the player exe - it's supposed to be able to figure out which application can work with the file type so that you don't have to.

Comment: video takes path of the exe file, and play has t run the video. in case i am chnaging vidoe path the quicktime .exe

Comment: Yes, I see that Viedo has the path of the exe, and you pass this to startfile - I am telling you that this is the wrong thing to do. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
self.path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QuickTimePlayer.exe"
```

to

```
self.path = path
```

Alternative:
Use `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()` - please see their documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: I tried to use sub process but that did not work , i may be doing somehting wrong                                                import subprocess
import os
print os.path.exists("C:/Users/A.mp4") 
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QuickTimePlayer.exe","\\C:/Users\\" + A+ '.mp4'])

Comment: Please edit your original question - this is very hard to read. In what way did it "not work"?